# Why did I lose 1 reputation?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

Is the reputation on superuser working properly ? My reputation just decreased from 101 to 100, without any adverse activity.

Answer (score 13):

You cast a downvote. That costs 1 rep (to discourage rampant revenge down-voting). Don't worry; you won't miss it.

Comment: I guess there was some delay in the rep getting updated.

Comment: also note that this only happens for a downvote cast on an answer

Comment: @Nate at the time I posted this, this was not the case, you are right now though.

Answer (score 7):

Did you downvote a question or answer? That subtracts 1 reputation from you.

Comment: Only answers now, not questions.